# rfm9x.receive() - Python LoRa receive method drops the first 4 characters

Tags: python, c, arduino, lora

I'm planning to set up a local LoRa network with a receiver (running Python on Raspberry Pi Zero) and several transmitters (running C code on Arduino).

To start on this I was testing some sketches from Adafruit and several other online tutorials and could get a transmitter and receiver to communicate using the RFM95 module.

But the issue is when the Python code reads the LoRa packet it drops the first 4 characters from the packet transmitted by the source.

What could be done to fix this? I suspect this could be a byte/string conversion issue, but I couldn't get it to work yet.

Transmitter code (C on Arduino):

```c
....
void loop() {
  Serial.print("Sending - Packet:");
  Serial.println(msgCount);
  LoRa.beginPacket();
  LoRa.print("Packet:");
  LoRa.print(msgCount);
  LoRa.endPacket();
  msgCount++;
  delay(5000);
}
.......
```

Receiver code (Python on PiZero):

```py
.......
while True:
    packet = None
    packet = rfm9x.receive()
    if packet is None:
        print('Waiting for PKT')
    else:
        prev_packet = packet
        packet_text = str(prev_packet, "utf-8")
        print(packet_text)
        time.sleep(1)
    time.sleep(0.1)
........
```

Expected output at the receiver:

```
Packet:1
Packet:2
Packet:3
.......
Packet:10
Packet:11
........
```

Actual output at the receiver:

```
et:1
et:2
et:3
.......
et:10
et:11
.......
```

I tried the below functions/methods without any success:

```
packet_text = prev_packet.decode("ascii", 'ignore')
packet_text = prev_packet.decode("utf-8", 'ignore')
```

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: I wonder why you never got `Waiting for PKT`.

Comment: I'm sorry... You are correct. The "Waiting for PKT" lines where there in the output. Just wanted to focus on the "else:" part of the while loop. That's why I omitted those lines. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you missed the documentation of [RFM9x.receive()](https://docs.circuitpython.org/projects/rfm9x/en/latest/api.html#adafruit_rfm9x.RFM9x.receive):

> receive(*, keep_listening: bool = True, with_header: bool = False, with_ack: bool = False, timeout: float | None = None) → bytearray | None
>
> Wait to receive a packet from the receiver. If a packet is found the payload bytes
> are returned, otherwise None is returned (which indicates the timeout elapsed with no
> reception).
> If keep_listening is True (the default) the chip will immediately enter listening mode
> after reception of a packet, otherwise it will fall back to idle mode and ignore any
> future reception.
> All packets must have a 4-byte header for compatibility with the
> RadioHead library.
> The header consists of 4 bytes (To,From,ID,Flags). The default setting will  strip
> the header before returning the packet to the caller.
> If with_header is True then the 4 byte header will be returned with the packet.
> The payload then begins at packet[4].
> If with_ack is True, send an ACK after receipt (Reliable Datagram mode)

> What could be done to fix this?

One could send a header or use `with_header = True`.

Comment: Thanks! In fact I didn't look at this doc :-) I went through some further examples and changed the transmitter code to add 4 bytes to the header at the beginning:  (To,From,ID,Flags) as noted in the doc.